# updates in symfony's code are not rendering

Tags: symfony, caching, twig, updates

I'm developing a web application with symfony2 ,A few days ago I noticed that changes/updates in code(pages.html.twig) are not rendering,I restarted the server but no luck,I tried to remove the twig folder from app/cache and I removed  the cache with this command

rm -rf app/cache/*

without success I added

twig:

cache: false

to my config_dev.yml but the problem still not solved . Any suggestions please ?!

Comment: I would suspect that you are editing the wrong file.  Check to see if you have the same file elsewhere in your project.  I know it sounds a bit silly but it actually happens more often then you might think.

Answer (score 0):

To clear your production cache, from your Symfony's project root directory enter:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

This is documented here for reference:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

Comment: Hmmm.  They already tried removing the entire cache directory.  How will your suggestion do more?

Comment: Correct @Cerad deleting the cache directory "should" do it. My answer is not an answer to the problem, but an answer to how to clear the cache properly. Deleting the "cache" folder is not normally done. I just realized this is symfony2 - I'll update the command too.

Comment: @AlvinBunk thanks for your reply , it generates an error : Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken.

Comment: Hi there Imane. Can you check the Production logs in the folder `var/logs/prod.log` and see what that shows. The "500" error is a generic error. Another thing you might try is the debug URL, which is just `app_dev.php` appended to the URL you would normally use - This might give you more helpful messages.

Comment: @AlvinBunk ,now I'm getting a new error during the authentication **An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT... no such table user ** I have user in my database, I regenerate the database schema but without success any help please ?!

Comment: Post a different question please!

Comment: @AlvinBunk this is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888991/authentication-not-allowed-after-clearing-cache-of-symfony2