# Authentication not allowed after clearing cache of symfony2

Tags: authentication, caching, orm, twig

I had a problem with my symfony's cache (changes in html pages were not rendering ) after many Attempts now I can not authenticate to the web site ,it shows me this error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.username AS
>   ......... FROM "fos_user" t0 WHERE
>   t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["1999999"]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: fos_user

in my fos/userbundle/entity/User.php I have these parameters :

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`fos_user`")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperClass
 */
class User
{
.............
```

and in my Bse/mybundle/entity/User.php I have these parameters :

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`fos_user`")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperClass
 */
class User
{.....
```

the table in the database is called **fos_user**

I'm using `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod',false);`in my app.php and `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);` in my app_dev.php

I'm asking for your help please

Answer (score 0):

You've got no table `fos_user`, which is the problem.

Can you try:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

See if that does the trick. I'm thinking you made a big change somehow and deleted the table? If the above doesn't work, edit your post and show the file `app/config/parameters.yml` please.

Comment: I have already tested this solution but without success,this is my parameters.yml                                                                                                              parameters:
   `database_driver: pdo_sqlite
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '1'
    database_name: xxx
    database_user: root
    database_password: password
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: fr
    secret: xxxx
    database_path: '1' `

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure: are you using Symfony. If so [check this link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database). SQLite requires this: `path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sqlite.db'` which I don't see in your parameters.